# ROS - ROAR compile error on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, robotics, ros

I am trying to install `ROAR` on Ubuntu 14.04 following this tutorial: http://wiki.ros.org/roar

However, I am stuck on `Compiling` step 3.2 `rosmake roar --rosdep-install`
I get an error `error: sudo: rosmake: command not found`

I downloaded 
`svn co https://mediabox.grasp.upenn.edu/svn/penn-ros-pkgs/roar_stack/trunk ~/ros/roar_stack` into my home directory, not `/opt/ros`
and set PATH to `export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=~/ros:$/home/myfolder/ros/roar_stack`

What am I doing wrong?

**update** I installed a clean version of `Ubuntu 14.04` on VMware and installed `ROS Jade` and the same problem persists.

Comment: Probably `sudo` is configured to clear your environment, that's why it could not find `rosmake` (it overrides your PATH with a "generic" one). Do following steps:

1. sudo -i

2. export environment variables

3. try to install

Comment: @nsilent22 thank you for the help.  I followed your steps but got the same result.  i tried it with and without `sudo`

Comment: Guessing from the command name: `rosmake` I think before installing ROAR you should install [ROS](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS) to get all the tools.

Comment: but when i run `roscore` i can communicate between nodes.

Comment: And what if you type `rosmake`?

Comment: i see what you mean, `command not found`

Comment: I rebooted and now `rosmake -h` returns data, but i ran your steps then tried to run `rosmake` and now getting `command not found`

Comment: What `which rosmake` returns?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83908/discussion-between-t-q-and-nsilent22).